# Why can't use create method when not all attributes are in $fillable array in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel framework and I am trying to create a new record in the table "product"
and the table has 4 fields ('id','name','price','sec').
when I am writing this code a new row is added to the table successfully

```
class productModel extends Model
{
    public $fillable = ['price','name'];
    public $table = 'product';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public static function add(){
        $model = new productModel();
        $model->price = 6;    
        $model->name = 'pro2';
        $model->sec = 33;
        $model->save();
    }
}
```

but when I write this code an error shows:
**QLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'sec' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `product` (`name`, `price`) values (Flight 10, 44))**

```
class productModel extends Model
{
    public $fillable = ['price','name'];
    public $table = 'product';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public static function add(){
        productModel::create(['name' => 'Flight 10','price' => 44,'sec' => 
        'content']);
    }
}
```

but when I put the 'sec' field in the $fillable array it works well so what the problem?

Comment: This is expected behavior. That is the whole point of the fillable array. The `$fillable` array defines properties that can be mass assigned allowing you to safely do stuff like `productModel::create($request->all())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is coming from your database, not Laravel.

When you assign the value explicitly (as in your first snippet), you aren't mass assigning it, so it doesn't matter what's in `$fillable`. You're giving it a value, so your database is happy.

When you don't have 'sec' in the fillable array, it's not getting assigned a value when you use `create` (which is mass-assigning the values). So, when Laravel goes to save your data, it's passing `null` to the database, which then responds with, "hey, this field isn't nullable and there's no default, so you have to tell me what to put into it."

So, your options are:

1. Update your database schema to make the field nullable, or add a default value at the database level.
2. Put "sec" into your `$fillable` array, so that it can be mass-assigned.
3. Set it explicitly somewhere in the create flow (either where you're setting the data or in some middleware layer, such as validation).

Which way you choose will depend on your needs.