# protected $fillable is not working in laravel 9

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

I tried to insert data where specific column was absent in $fillable attribute.Instead of MassAssignmentException error it worked.

Scenarion is like that

My model name is Subject.php:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'Subject',
    'Dept',
    'Session'
];
```

Migration:

```
Schema::create('subjects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('Subject');
        $table->string('Dept');
        $table->string('Session');
        $table->integer('type')->default(1);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Blade file:

```
 <form action="/store" method="post">
    @csrf
<input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="sb">
<input type="text" placeholder="Dept" name="dp">
<input type="text" placeholder="Session" name="sd">
<input type="text" placeholder="Type" name="ty">
<button type="submit">Add</button>
```

Here you can see i added type input field to insert but it was absent in fillable attribute above.

When i access NormalController.php through `/store` route , it work perfectly and insert data into database.

NormalController.php:

```
$ins =Subject::create([

    'Subject'=>$request->sb,
     'Dept'=>$request->dp,
     'Session'=>$request->sd,
     'type'=>$request->ty

  ]);

  if($ins){
    echo"Success";
  }
```

I tried to understand from this link but didn't:

```
1.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45512679/why-cant-use-create-method-when-not-all-attributes-are-in-fillable-array-in-la

2.https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/fillable-and-create-not-working
```

Hope, you will help me.
Thanks.

Comment: When you say that it worked, are you saying that it failed to give an error or that it actually created the row with the data entered in the form (not the default value)?

Comment: @mankowitz yes ,it failed to give an error that was desired.

Comment: @mankowitz  In the presence of default->(1),it insert a data into databae.Otherwise it give error named "Field 'type' doesn't have a default value".

Comment: why do you think it doesn't work? there is no error thrown, it is a whitelist, not a blacklist

Comment: @lagbox i missed the quote that mankowitz mentioned.Actually i was reading a blog where it was said that an error  will error throw in this situation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as expected. According to [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#mass-assignment):

> By default, attributes that are not included in the $fillable array are silently discarded when performing mass-assignment operations.

If you want it to throw an exception, you can add this to your AppServiceProvider.php:

```
public function boot(): void
{
    Model::preventSilentlyDiscardingAttributes(true);
}
```